# How can a video card support more monitors than it has ports?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I'm looking into buying a new video card and I really like the [GeForce GTX 650 Ti](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-650ti). Looking at the features list, it claims:

> **NVIDIA Surround with Up To Four Monitors**
>
> Nothing is as breathtaking as playing your favorite games across three monitors. At 5760 x 1080, the expanded field of view fully engages human peripheral vision and provides for the most immersive experience in racing and flight simulators. Add in a fourth display to keep tabs on chat, email or web while you are gaming.

However, looking at the specs, it only has three ports: two DVI and one HDMI. So how can it support four displays? Is there some trick to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround with up to four monitors is a feature of the 600-series range of GPUs. You are correct that the *reference* design 650 ti only has three outputs. However there are quite a few non-reference design cards that have four outputs, such as the Gigabyte GV-N65TOC-2GI.  [Here is a link to the product page for that model.](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4382#ov)

Comment: I see, so it's a difference between the chip itself and the board it's attached to?

Comment: Yes. Reference design cards follow Nvidia's (or AMD's) specifications for power, cooling, and output layouts/designs. Individual manufacturers take the Nvidia/AMD card and slap their company's logo on them. Non-reference cards use the same GPU chip, but manufacturers have some elasticity in terms of adding power phases, designing more efficient coolers, and reconfiguring the outputs. In the end though, their changes must be supported by the chip, obviously.